# Index-Error: string index out of range -

Tags: python

```
def find_starman(board):
    row_number = 0
    column_number = 0

for star in board:
        for j in range(len(board):
           for i in range(len(board):
               if star[j][i] == '*':
                    j += 1
                    i += 1
     return [j,i]
```

I have no idea, everytime I ran the program, it says it is out of range?
How can I fix this?
(Also, forgot to say the question, when if finds the "*" it returns j+1 and i+1 )

Comment: Make sure `star` is a list of at least 5 lists of at least 5 elements each.  From the error, it isn't.

Comment: Also, don't try to modify `i` and `j` manually, it probably won't behave as you expect.

Comment: What is `board` (I'm assuming is iterable of some kind). Also, make sure you past valid code. I see missing closing parentheses in the two inner for loops and the indentation is wrong. That code won't run, so is not very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `for` loops, you don't need to increment the iterator in the loop body as it will automatically update to the new value after each loop (in this case, an increment of 1 since you're assigning it to iterate over `range` with steps of 1).

In other words, these lines are unnecessary:

```
j += 1
i += 1
```

Furthermore, from your edited question, it seems you'd like to return the coordinates `(i+1, j+1)` of the found `*`'s. In that case:

1) If you want to return those coordinates for only the first `*` you can find, and immediately exit the function, you can do:

```
if star[j][i] == '*':
   return (j+1, i+1)
```

2) If you want to return the coordinates for all the `*`'s in your array, you can create new variables (like an empty list) before you build your loop, and for every run of the `for` loop, store the `i+1` and `j+1` of the found `*` as a child tuple/list to that variable (using `append`). In other words, something like this:

```
found_coordinates = []
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board)):
        if star[i][j] == '*':
            found_coordinates.append((j+1, i+1))
```

In any case, your iterators (`i` and `j`) are either immediately returned or stored in another object, and should not be modified (using `+=` or something else) inside a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove j+=1 and i+=1 from your code and modify your return like this: return(j+1, i+1). I think thats what you want to do.

```
 if star[j][i] == '*': 
         return [j+1,i+1]
```